# How to "hide" a virtual method? (C++)

Tags: c++, abstract

there is a post with a quite similar title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898245/how-to-hide-virtual-method-in-c-and-keep-interface), but as I understood the actual problem there is different.

I would like to know if it is possible to force a user of a class i wrote to override a certain method but at the same time it should not be possible to call this method (but its only called from within my class).

For example, if I want to do the following:

```
class AbstrDataSource {
private:
    int index;    
protected:
    int currentData;    
public:
    int getData(){return currentData;}
    void loadData(int i){
        // check valid index here
        if (index != i){doLoad(i);}
        this->index = i;
    }
    virtual void doLoad(int i)=0;
};
```

In loadData() I can check that the index is in a valid range and do some bookkeeping, while the actual loading has to be supplied by the user via overriding doLoad(). Because pure virtual methods are part of the interface, they are public, but how do I force the implementation of doLoad() to be visible only to my own class?

My idea was to hide the object in some wrapper:

```
class DataSupplier {
public:
    DataSupplier(AbstrDataSource* s) : source(s){}
    void loadData(int i){source->loadData(i);}
    int getData(){return source->getData();}
private:
    AbstrDataSource* source;
};
```

And instead of using the abstract class I use the wrapper:

```
int SomeCalculation(DataSupplier* a,DataSupplier* b){
    return a->getData() + b->getData();
}
```

However, this does not really help. Lets say a second person provides a implementation of my abstract class:

```
class ImplDataSource : public AbstrDataSource{
public:
    void doLoad(int i){this->currentData = i;}
};
```

Then a third person still has access to doLoad():

```
void main(){
    AbstrDataSource* ads = new ImplDataSource();
    DataSupplier* ds1 = new DataSupplier(ads);
    DataSupplier* ds2 = new DataSupplier(ads);
    ads->doLoad(10); // <- How to avoid this ??
    ds1->loadData(12);
    ds2->loadData(12);
    SomeCalculations(ds1,ds2);
}
```

Maybe there is a way to achieve this by using access specifiers...?

EDIT: I already got some helpful answers, but I think I did not state my question clear enough. As long as ImplDataSource declares doLoad() as protected or private, everything is fine. However, looking only at AbstrDataSource, there is no hint that any implementation of doLoad() should be private (even if the abstract doLoad was protected or private the actual implementation can have any access). I would like to know if it is possible to somehow "enforce" any implementation of the abstract doLoad() to be private. Maybe I am just thinking too complicated and the easiest way would be to add a comment to the documentation of the abstract method ("implement as private or it may fail").

Comment: Why do you need `doLoad` to be public? Wouldn't it be sufficient to make it protected?

Comment: Don't forget virtual destructor.

Comment: @user1781290 : or even make `doLoad` private, instead of just protected.

Comment: @user1781290 I think I read somewhere that abstract methods should be public, as by definition they are part of the (public) interface of the class. And anyway, making doLoad() private in AbstrDataSource does not prevent it to be public in ImplDataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the method doLoad() protected, then it can only be called from within the superclass, and it overloads (and hides) the pure virtual method of the base class.

Comment: Making it protected means it can be called by derived classes too (ie. not just the base classes). Making it private will prevent that.

Comment: That's right, but that's not the problem as far as I understood. The end of the post talks about a 'third person' calling the method, with an example calling the function through an object pointer from the main function. This would no longer be possible.

Comment: Unless that 'third person' derives from `ImplDataSource`.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I am sorry, but I think I introduced some unnecessary confusion by talking about different persons. I will edit the question to make it more clear. @Rene making doLoad() protected in AbstrDataSrouce does not prevent ImplDataSource to implement it as public.

Comment: Before your edit, my answer was the solution for your problem: Make the method doLoad() protected or private in the class ImplDataSource, then it cannot be called from the outside.<br>

Comment: After your edit my answer would be: You cannot enforce a specific visibility of the doLoad() method in subclasses. Your design already corresponds to the 'template method pattern' mentioned by some ppl here, but this pattern also does not provide a solution for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, after some further reading I understood that there is really no way to achieve what I wanted. I guess the closest to what I was looking for is to make doLoad() protected in the AbstrDataSource and make some clear statement in the documentation that anybody implementing AbstrDataSource should make doLoad() protected otherwise, any user of this implementation (with a public doLoad()) can bypass the functionality added by the base class (i.e. anything done in loadData()).

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is called the template method pattern and
I think the best you can do here is to delegate to the doLoad method the less "sensitive" behavior and put the loadData (and the part you wanna hide from the derived class) in private access